# Venn Diagram (event not occuring)

Tags: probability

On a site which provides practice questions for the Florida math teacher certification test, I saw a Venn Diagram question:

The probability that an event A will not occur, 1-A, is represented in a Venn Diagram as ________.

The link below shows the various diagrams, and says that C is the answer (where A is circled and A with a line above represents the space outside of the Venn circle.

http://www.testprepreview.com/ftce-mathematics-6-12.htm

Without more information, could not the opposite (choice B) also be correct? I feel this is a sloppy question that wouldn't be asked on a real standardized test, but want to check here.

Comment: $(A^c)^c = A$.  So if $B = A^c$ then $B^c = A$.  So, yeah. B is a legitimate answer.

Comment: I will point out that question ten on the linked practice exam is incorrect.  The negation of the phrase "Robert has black hair and Sally does not" should be "Robert does not have black hair **or** Sally does."  See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).  I don't like how the math is formatted on the site either.  As for your actual question, it is more by convention than anything else that we usually prefer having sets in the circles to be the ones not labeled with as the complementary event, while complements are outside of circles.